# How to create an installer for a Visual Studio Express 2013 Desktop project

Tags: sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-exp-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop and SQL server, and I want to know

- how to make an installer for a WinForm application that I developed.
- where I have to put the files that the software needs to do its job. These files are images, databases, etc.

Any help would be appreciated. (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to download installer project extension from this [link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)
- Then follow the [step by step guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568476/Creating-an-MSI-Setup-Package-for-Csharp-Windows) that how to select step project template and add files.